# c# access the second key's value from a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> Format
```

And I access the first value (first key value) like this:

```
Format.Values.First()
```

There is a simple possibility to access the 2'nd one like this?

```
Format.Values.Second()
```

EDITED

This is a settings dictionary with only 2 entries. I really don't understand downvotes, maybe someone will have this situation and really need those answers.

Comment: The values of a dictionary *are unordered*.

Comment: `Format.Values.Skip(1).First()` although the values in a dictionary are not ordered.

Comment: `Format.Values.Take(2).Last()`?

Comment: why don't you do a simple google search on how to read Dictionary Key / Value Pairs..

Comment: `Format.Values.ElementAt(1)` will also work.

Comment: How does the fact that your dictionary only have two entries make it any more sensible to ask for the second item *of an unordered collection*?  If you want to get the value of the second setting, provide the key for  your second setting to get its value.  That's what dictionaries are there for.  The fact that you "need" the answer doesn't change the fact that the fundamental operation doesn't make sense in the first place.  Anyone else who "needs the answer" should *also* be informed that dictionaries are unordered and so there is no "second value" to get.

Comment: When you say 'second' entry, what do you mean exactly? The one that was added second? The one with the second key, in alphabetical order? Something else?

Comment: The one added second. Makes more sense to use an array[]. I never sort or use as dictionary anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Skip(int)` method.

```
Format.Values.Skip(1).First()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use

```
Format.Values.ElementAt(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Format[Format.Keys.ToList()[1]];
```